# C++ virtual method pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

Im writing a simple socket server in C++. I've already have some libs from C which fires callback when event read happens on socket. I want client who will use that class will impement its own mechanims to handle those events. 
My base class is:

```
class CBaseServer{
    ...
    void monitorDataArrived(int fd);
    virtual void monitorOnDataArrived(void *context, int fd) = 0;
}
```

in this class pointer to `monitorOnDataArrived(void *context, int fd)` has to be passed to extarnal C function called `AddClient(int mask, proc, fd)` whenever new socket will appear.  `proc` is defined as:

```
typedef void(*proc)(void *context, int fd)
CBaseServer::monitorDataArrived(fd){
     proc p = (void (*)(void*, int)&CBase::monitorOnDataArrived; 
     addClient(MASK_READ, p, fd);
}
```

now client is doing:

```
class Reader : class CBase{
    void monitorOnDataArrived(void *context, int fd) {
        std::cout << "hey, data arrived"
    }
}
```

My question is: im having compliation errors: `undefined refernece to CBaseServer::monitorOnDataArrived(void *, int)`

Is there any way to fix it ?

regards
J.

Comment: You cannot hope to make this work. An instance method is not compatible with your `proc` type. Didn't alarm bells go off when you found you had to cast it. The compiler said that your instance method was no good. But you said, "I know better, just pretend that I am right". Remove the cast and think again. It rather looks to me as though you are allowed to pass a pointer in `context` and that is how you are expected to get the instance all the way back to your callback. But maybe not.

Comment: I add this casting cause i had error that types are incorret: error: cannot convert 'void (CBaseServer::*)(void*,int) to void( *)(void *, int)

Comment: Does `AddClient` have a variant that allows providing a `context` argument that will be passed to the callback? What does the documentation say will be passed as the `context` argument to that callback?

Comment: The compiler told you that you had made a mistake. Why did you decide that it was wrong and you were right? You really do need to make a shift of mindset. When the compiler reports an error, you need to think about why it did so, and not just decide to ignore and suppress it.

Comment: My fault when i was writing code here. My question was more like: what is the differnece between 'void (CBaseServer::*)(void*,int) to void( *)(void *, int), since they both end as a pointers in compiled code

Comment: The difference is that the former is a pointer to a non-static member function `CBaseServer`, where the latter is a function. The calls of the two are executed and implemented differently - the member function must be attached to an instance of `CBaseServer` (or subclass), while the global function is not. In the presence of virtual methods and/or multiple inheritance, there are more differences, such as run-time dispatch of the method.

Answer (score 3):

You are misunderstanding the function pointers in C++.

You cannot pass a member function to a C handler, since a member function has an additional implicit parameter (the "this" parameter).

What is the solution? The solution is to use static functions which will cast the void * context parameter into an instance of your base class, and then calling the virtual function:

```
class CBaseServer{
    ...
    //Watch that the context parameter has been moved from the virtual to the other
    //function, which is now also static.
    static void monitorDataArrived(void *context, int fd);
    virtual void monitorOnDataArrived(int fd) = 0;
}
```

The dispatching code would be as following:

```
void CBaseServer::monitorDataArrived(void *context, int fd){
    CBaseServer * server=(CBaseServer*)context;
    server->monitorOnDataArrived(fd);
}
```

And the registration code would be:

```
class Reader : class CBase{
    void monitorOnDataArrived(int fd) {
        std::cout << "hey, data arrived"
    }
}
....
Reader * theReader=new Reader();

//The instance theReader of type Reader must be passed to the registration function
//as the void * context parameter.
addClient(MASK_READ, &theReader);
```

Comment: This is all nice, except `AddClient` as presented in the OP has a signature that doesn't allow passing of a context pointer. See my comment on the question...

Comment: @user4815162342 It is true. I think that the OP has misunderstood the usage of addClient. Since the callback function has a "context" pointer, it is usually used to pass data not used by the library directly from the registration to the callback function, so the addClient must have a context parameter also. Other way, it would not make sense to have a void* context parameter in the callback... Lets see if the OP clarifies the signature of addClient...

Comment: Agreed. Interestingly, the OP refers to `AddClient` as the external C function, but we only ever see the call to `addClient`. This might be a typo, but it could also be the case that `addClient` is a utility method calling `AddClient` with NULL context (among other parameters).